# Puedo ir de la vista de inicio a otra vista , pero alli ya no puedo ir a otra vista

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

estoy experimentando dificultades para cambiar de vista una vez que estás en una vista abierta, a pesar de que la URL en la barra de direcciones se actualiza correctamente, usando ve.js version dos y router version 3..5.1
Mis archivos son :
Index.js , que contiene las rutas

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import BiologiaActual from '../views/biologia.vue'
import QuimicaActual from '../views/quimica.vue'
import InicioView from '@/views/Inicio.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'InicioView',
    component:InicioView
  },
  {
    path: '/biologia',
    name: 'BiologiaActual',
    component:BiologiaActual
  },
  {
    path: '/quimica',
    name: 'QuimicaActual',
    component:QuimicaActual
  },
  {
    path: '/fisica',
    name: 'FisicaActual',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/FisicaActual.vue')
  },

   
  
  
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <BarraNavegacion></BarraNavegacion>
    
      <router-view></router-view>
    
    
    
 
    
   
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BarraNavegacion from './components/BarraNavegacion.vue';


export default {
  name: "App",
  data(){
    
  },
  components: {
    BarraNavegacion,
    
  },
  
}


</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Componente BarraNavegacion.vue

```
<template>
  
    <v-app-bar app color="grey">
      <v-toolbar-title>Ciencias Naturales</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn text @click="navigate('InicioView')"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>  Inicio</v-btn>
      <v-btn text @click="navigate('BiologiaActual')"><i class="fas fa-microscope"></i>Biología</v-btn>
      <v-btn text @click="navigate('FisicaActual')"><i class="fas fa-radiation"></i> Física</v-btn>
      <v-btn text @click="navigate('QuimicaActual')"><i class="fas-vial"></i>Química</v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    navigate(route) {
      if (this.$route.name !== route && this.$route.path !== route) {
        this.$router.push({ name: route });
      }
    },
  },
  
};
</script>
```

Vista Inicio.vue

```
<template>
   <h1>Bienvenidos a la ciencia</h1>
</template>
<script>


export default {
  name: "inicioView",
  components: {
     
  },
  data(){
}
}
</script>
```

Vista biologia.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
      
   
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Biologia  Impresionante</h1>
        <!-- Aquí puedes agregar el contenido adicional de la vista -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
 
  export default {
  name: 'BiologiaActual',
  components:{
     
  }
}
  
  </script>
  
  <style>
  .content {
    margin-top: 64px; /* Ajusta el margen superior para evitar que se solape con la barra de navegación */
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  </style>
```

Vista quimica.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
      
   
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Quimica Impresionante</h1>
        <!-- Aquí puedes agregar el contenido adicional de la vista -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
 
  export default {
  name: 'QuimicaActual',
  components:{
     
  }
}
  
  </script>
  
  <style>
  .content {
    margin-top: 64px; /* Ajusta el margen superior para evitar que se solape con la barra de navegación */
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  </style>
```

Vista FisicaActual.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
      
   
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Física Impresionante</h1>
        <!-- Aquí puedes agregar el contenido adicional de la vista -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
 
  export default {
  name: 'FisicaActual',
  components:{
     
  }
}
  
  </script>
  
  <style>
  .content {
    margin-top: 64px; /* Ajusta el margen superior para evitar que se solape con la barra de navegación */
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  </style>
```

Mi proyecto tiene las siguientes vistas , Inicio.vue , FisicaActual.vue , biologia.vue , quimica.vue . Los botones para navegar estan en el componente Barranavegacion.vue que esta ubicado fuera de la etiqueta routerview en la vista App.vue . Al ingresar observo en las url en la barra de direcciones que se navega bien , pero desde la pagina de inicio que Inicio.vue solamente puedo abrir una vista y una vez en la vista abirta ya no puedo cambiar de vista , aunque en la barra de direcciones veo que la url cambia ¿ que se puede hacer?

Answer (score 0):

comencé a probar diferentes alternativas , me di cuenta que el problema de navegacion se presentaba con el archivo Inicio.vue , porque entre las otras vistas se podía navegar sin dificultad . Compare las vistas y me di cuenta que la vista Inicio.vue en la etiqueta script despues de los componentes tenía el siguiente fragmento de codigo  data() {},. lo borre y al probarlo nuevamente comenzó a funcionar bien . De todas maneras si alguien puede explicarme porque es fragmento de codigo interfería la navegación sería genial.

Comment: y no tenias ningun error en la consola???